Change adjacent elements of a python series
I have a python series which has boolean values. Wherever there is a True in the series, I want the previous 5 values and the next 6 values to be true.
I could achieve it using a for loop but I want to know if I can achieve it using a built in function.

Does this answer your question? How do you insert into a list by slicing?

Hi, welcome to SO! Do you mean a pandas series? Please add a [mre]. E.g., use s.head().to_dict(), where s is your pd.Series, and post between triple backticks (```). Please show both input and output (based on the provided input).

Here's another possible solution which consists of:

Identifying which indices have a True
Iterating over each of these and adjusting neighboring values

x = np.array([
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1]).astype(bool)

# step 1: find indices where entries are True
true_indices = [i for i, value in enumerate(s) if value]

# step 2: adjust neighboring values
for idx in true_indices:
    s[max(0, idx-5):min(len(s), idx+7)] = True

Thanks to @dankal444 for the little example :)

This is bit of a hack, using convolution. If you plan to use it, add some comment what this part of code does for future readers.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


the_series = pd.DataFrame({'series': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                      0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})['series'] == 1

result = np.convolve(the_series, np.arange(13), mode='same') > 0
combined_df = pd.DataFrame({'the_series': the_series, 'result': result})


